# How can I obtain the unit of a projection SRID?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, proj, units

Given a projection SRID, is there a way I can obtain the coordinates unit string (*meter*, *degree*, ...) ?

In PostGIS for example, it looks like it is present in the `srtext` column of `spatial_ref_sys`. Should I parse that block of text or is there a shortcut somewhere ?

Is there something in libproj directly ?

Thanks !

Comment: srtext is a good place; `proj4text` contains the units as well.

Comment: It might help if you can tell us what the object of this question is. That is, what are you going to do with the units. If you can specify that, we might be able to help with solving the underlying issue in a way that doesn't involve parsing things by hand...

Comment: My initial goal is to make sure that the projection is in meters (an assertion in some of my application code...).